# In VB.NET how do you specify Inherits/implements on a generic class with multi-constraints

Tags: vb.net, constraints, generics

When I write the following statement in VB.Net (C# is my normal language), I get an "end of statement expected" referring to the "Implements" statement.

```
<Serializable()> _
<XmlSchemaProvider("EtgSchema")> _
Public Class SerializeableEntity(Of T As {Class, ISerializable, New}) _
Implements IXmlSerializable, ISerializable
...
End Class
```

The C# version that I'm trying to emulate is:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlSchemaProvider("MySchema")]
public class SerializableEntity<T> : IXmlSerializable, ISerializable where T : class, new()
{
....
}
```

Sometimes I feel like I have 5 thumbs with VB.NET :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VB, `Implements` (and `Inherits`) is a separate clause *within* the body of the class (on the same level as class members), so you simply need to drop that `_` line continuation:

```
<Serializable()> _
<XmlSchemaProvider("EtgSchema")> _
Public Class SerializeableEntity(Of T As {Class, ISerializable, New})
    Implements IXmlSerializable, ISerializable
    ...
End Class
```

Comment: Weird, when I put everything on the same line it gives me the message same as when I add the _ for continuation.  But works as above when I don't add a continuation but put it on the next line.  

Thank you for the answer, it should have been obvious.

Comment: That's the point. When you put everything on the same line, it's exactly the same as when you separate lines by `_` (it's the whole point of a line continuation character - it effectively suppresses the following newline, as if it wasn't there).